# Reindex Pandas and insert a numpy array of zeros

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, reindex

I have a pandas dataframe `df`:

```
    Date                Activity Vector
0   2017-03-01T15:20:00 [0.0366666666667, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0...
1   2017-03-01T15:25:00 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
2   2017-03-01T15:45:00 [0.163333333333, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...
3   2017-03-01T15:50:00 [0.316666666667, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...
4   2017-03-01T15:55:00 [0.0666666666667, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0...
5   2017-03-01T16:00:00 [0.123333333333, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...
6   2017-03-01T16:05:00 [0.0333333333333, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0...
7   2017-03-01T16:10:00 [0.356666666667, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...
8   2017-03-01T16:15:00 [0.476666666667, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...
9   2017-03-01T16:20:00 [0.113333333333, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...
10  2017-03-01T16:50:00 [0.0733333333333, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0...
```

This data is a time series with some missing values (note, the `Date` column has type `str`).

I would like to reindex this dataframe and fill the missing entries with a numpy vector of zeros, `np.zeros(15)`

I've tried the following:

```
df = data.clean_df[['Date', 'Activity Vector']]
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
# print(df.dtypes)
df = df.set_index('timestamp').resample('300S').ffill()
```

which gives me the following:

```
    timestamp           Date                Activity Vector
0   2017-03-01 15:20:00 2017-03-01T15:20:00 [0.0366666666667, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0...
1   2017-03-01 15:25:00 2017-03-01T15:25:00 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
2   2017-03-01 15:30:00 2017-03-01T15:25:00 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
3   2017-03-01 15:35:00 2017-03-01T15:25:00 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
4   2017-03-01 15:40:00 2017-03-01T15:25:00 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
5   2017-03-01 15:45:00 2017-03-01T15:45:00 [0.163333333333, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...
6   2017-03-01 15:50:00 2017-03-01T15:50:00 [0.316666666667, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...
7   2017-03-01 15:55:00 2017-03-01T15:55:00 [0.0666666666667, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0...
8   2017-03-01 16:00:00 2017-03-01T16:00:00 [0.123333333333, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...
9   2017-03-01 16:05:00 2017-03-01T16:05:00 [0.0333333333333, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0...
10  2017-03-01 16:10:00 2017-03-01T16:10:00 [0.356666666667, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
```

However this fills the missing samples with the previous entry via the `ffill`, how can I instead fill the new rows with custom entries, for example with `Date` being anything (doesn't matter as it will be dropped later) but `Activity Vector` being filled with a numpy vector of zeros, `np.zeros(15)`

Comment: You can use fillna: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Comment: please, make the sample data smaller.  this is very hard to read and you could make the point just as easily with a tiny dataframe.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Thanks for the advice, edited out most samples. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say `Date being anything (doesn't matter as it will be dropped later)`, instead of `ffill` you can use `asfreq` and then fill the `NaN` data with the desired list or string you want.

If you want the numpy array as a string you can use str. If you want the array as a list like your example you can use `ast.literal_eval()`

```
import ast
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
# print(df.dtypes)
df = df.set_index('timestamp').resample('300S').asfreq()
df['Activity Vector'] = df['Activity Vector'].fillna(str(np.zeros(15).tolist())).apply(str)
df['Activity Vector'] = df['Activity Vector'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Did this help ?